# Flutter: I am missing the image parameter

Tags: flutter, class, object, state

I have a class where my object are, I tried calling it out in another file where I want to make use of the properties, It is telling me required named parameter 'image' must be provided.

```
class _homeState extends State<home> {
  var _currentIndex = 0;
  final screens = [
    HomePage(),
    Categories(),
    const NearYou(image: '', title: '', subtitle: '',),
    Cart(),
    Profile()
  ];
```

I really don't know what to put in those parameters above
Also, It is saying:  Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
Will I also call my class in that file?

```
class NearYou extends StatefulWidget {
 final String image;
  final String title;
  final String subtitle;

  const NearYou(
      {Key? key,
      required this.image,
      required this.title,
      required this.subtitle})
      : super(key: key);
```

Comment: you're missing the `image` parameter in `NearYou(image: '', title: '', subtitle: '',)`

Comment: Help me out. I don't know what it is

Comment: Welcome to SO, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [minimum-reproducable-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MendelG I haven't gotten it